# How do I set up an Absinthe schema with field names different than underlying Ecto field names?

Tags: ecto, absinthe

For example, I'd like to call the `inserted_on` timestamp `created_at` in the front end in the following Absinthe schema:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Schema.AccountTypes do
  use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

  object :user do
    field :id, :id
    field :email, :string
    field :inserted_on, :datetime
  end
end
```

but I'm not sure how to setup the Ecto <-> Absinthe mapping. Should I just add a virtual field to my Ecto schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the :source option in Ecto schemas for database fields, so you can use your own internal name:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Schema.AccountTypes do
  use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

  object :user do
    field :id, :id
    field :email, :string
    field :created_at, :datetime, source: :inserted_on
  end
end
```

But the best option would probably be to set the proper field name in the query macro:

```
defmodule My.Schema do
  use Absinthe.Schema
  query do
    field :created_at, :string do
      resolve &MyResolver.inserted_on/3
  end
end
```

.. or use your own datatype instead of string..

Comment: I tried the first solution (of course, applied to my data structure), but got this error:
` ** (KeyError) key :source not found  expanding struct:: Absinthe.Type.Field.__struct__/1`
Is it possible that this `source` option was removed from Absinthe?

Comment: It's a relatively new feature, so maybe check your ecto version. It's decribed here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3